# Connection to MySQL is working in Debug mode and not working in Release

Tags: c#, mysql, debugging, connection, release

I'm connecting to MySQL via C# using MySQLHelper. Problem came when I released my app. In debug mode it's connecting fine, but in release it shows: **Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**

My connection string I hard-code, not storing in any config files. I thought problem might be in some compiler optimizations, but there are nothing to optimize. I even made some custom debug, showing variables after error. My connection string in release mode looks exactly the same as in debug mode.

I use MySQL from hosting. I have set it to remote connections. In fact its working in debug mode so its not this cause a problem.

Comment: Anything in the event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable... I solved it. 
It seems in debug mode C# could change hostname to IP in connection string. 
I tried to use IP instead of hostname in connection string and now it's working in Release mode also.